# string filed is truncated on SqlBulkCopy insert

Tags: c#, excel, sql-server-2012, sqlbulkcopy

I use SqlBulkCopy to insert excel data to table.

One of the fields is ntext on the destination table but when the data is inserted the data is truncated after 255 chars.

```
using (OleDbConnection conExcel = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
                {
                    DL_ID = library.Save();

                    conExcel.Open();

                    string sheet1 = conExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

                    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT " + Convert.ToString(DL_ID) + " as DL_ID,* FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", conExcel))
                    {
                        oda.Fill(dtExcelData.DefaultView.Table);

                    }
                    conExcel.Close();

                    string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
                    {

                        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                        {
                            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.IMPORTS_LIBRARY_DATA";

                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(0,"DL_ID");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(1,"ILD_OLD_ID");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(2,"ILD_Desc");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, "ILD_Unit");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add( 4,"ILD_Empty");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add( 5,"ILD_Price1");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add( 6,"ILD_Price2");

                            con.Open();
                            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                            con.Close();
                        }


                    }

                }
```

the filed that is truncated is `ILD_Desc`

i tried to change it to nvarchar(max) and it's still truncated.
i didnt get an error, just see the data truncated on destination table to 255 chars.

UPDATE:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IMPORTS_LIBRARY_DATA](
[ILD_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[DL_ID] [int] NULL,
[ILD_OLD_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ILD_Desc] [ntext] NULL,
[ILD_Unit] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ILD_Empty] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ILD_Price1] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ILD_Price2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ILD_Folder1] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ILD_Folder2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ILD_Folder3] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ILD_Date] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_IMPORTS_LIBRARY_DATA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ILD_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

GO

Comment: How long is the string?

Comment: it's can be more then 4000

Comment: so I did a quick search on excel character limits and found the following, might be an issue.     Well, according to Excel specifications the maximum length of cell contents (text) is 32,767 characters, but only 1,024 display in a cell. Also the maximum column width is 255 characters

Comment: the problem is in the mssql table. int the excel i see all the string, in the destination the string is cut.

Comment: Ah, I read that first sentence wrong, I am sorry.

Comment: What is the type and size of your database destination field?

Comment: i added un update to my question

Comment: Not related to your problem but it is better to change `ntext` to `nvarchar(max)`. Refer to here:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issues is with the OLEDB provider for excel.

> When you use OLEDB providers then the datatype is determined automatically by the provider based on the first 8 rows. If you have lengthy cells in the first 8 rows then data type will be set as text and otherwise it will be memo type which can hold 255 characters. To overcome this issue Either change the registry setting as mentioned in below KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281517 or use Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB provider to read the data.

OBS: You can change the registry setting called TypeGuessRows. Values range is from 0 to 16 (default is 8), but if you set 0, the number of rows scanned is 16384.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1913118.aspx?Microsoft+oledb+data+acces+truncates+the+data+length+to+255+characters

Comment: i Cant change the registry on every server :) , my solution was to insert a row to the excel with text more that 255 chars.